# VTP does not update VLANs in switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vtp

**Switch 1 will be server and Switch 4 will be Client!**

Switch 1 configuration

```
       S1#show run
   Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1451 bytes
!
version 16.3.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end







S1#show vtp st
        S1#show vtp status 
        VTP Version capable             : 1 to 2
        VTP version running             : 2
        VTP Domain Name                 : ccna
        VTP Pruning Mode                : Disabled
        VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
        Device ID                       : 0030.A3BA.9100
        Configuration last modified by 0.0.0.0 at 3-1-93 00:41:16
        Local updater ID is 0.0.0.0 (no valid interface found)

        Feature VLAN : 
        --------------
        VTP Operating Mode                : Server
        Maximum VLANs supported locally   : 1005
        Number of existing VLANs          : 7
        Configuration Revision            : 7
        MD5 digest                        : 0x44 0xD7 0x99 0x68 0xF8 0x18 0x7F 0xBD 
                                            0xA4 0xDE 0xB5 0xC3 0x00 0x69 0xC3 0xC6
```

Switch 4 configurations

```
  S4#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1390 bytes
!
version 16.3.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname S4
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
!
end 


S4#show vtp status 
VTP Version capable             : 1 to 2
VTP version running             : 2
VTP Domain Name                 : ccna
VTP Pruning Mode                : Disabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
Device ID                       : 0001.6436.1500
Configuration last modified by 0.0.0.0 at 3-1-93 00:15:42

Feature VLAN : 
--------------
VTP Operating Mode                : Client
Maximum VLANs supported locally   : 1005
Number of existing VLANs          : 5
Configuration Revision            : 1
MD5 digest                        : 0xA5 0xB4 0xB1 0x07 0x53 0x1C 0xB7 0x15 
                                    0x19 0x51 0x6B 0x51 0x4B 0xD0 0xD7 0xBA
```

Comment: I dont see any VTP configuration.

Comment: Sorry ! it's added at bottom!

Comment: How are the two switches connected? I don't see any Layer 3 interface on the two devices. If they are suppose to communicate, then you need to create a VLAN and assign an IP address so that they can communicate.

Comment: The very first thing to fix is that you have two different VTP passwords configured. The passwords must match for VTP to work.

Comment: By the way, you are probably learning VTP as part of a curriculum, and that is fine, but VTP is something you probably do not really want to use in production. It can cause major problems, and it can be a security risk. In the real world, smart people set the VTP mode to `transparent`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For VTP to work between a VTP server and client, the VTP Domain Name and VTP passwords must match. You have the same VTP Domain Name (`ccna`), but the VTP Passwords do not match. You can tell that the passwords do not match because the MD5 Digests do not match:

```
Switch 1: 0x44 0xD7 0x99 0x68 0xF8 0x18 0x7F 0xBD 0xA4 0xDE 0xB5 0xC3 0x00 0x69 0xC3 0xC6
Switch 4: 0xA5 0xB4 0xB1 0x07 0x53 0x1C 0xB7 0x15 0x19 0x51 0x6B 0x51 0x4B 0xD0 0xD7 0xBA
```

You can use the `show vtp password` command on each switch to see the password configured on the switch. Remember that having a space before or after the password is part of the password, and it will be difficult to tell if that is the case. Also, a blank password is a password.

To fix it, you can copy a password once, then paste it into both switches. That way, you can make sure that they are the same.

Comment: Actually password is not configured! Oppss